# The exact number of points within a circle of radius r centered on a lattice point in a hexagonal lattice? Review expression Gauss circle problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lattices

In the case of a square lattice, the exact number of points within a circle of radius r centered in the center is (see: [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html):
$$N(r)=1+4Floor(r)+4 \sum_{x=1}^{Floor(r)}{Floor(\sqrt{r^2−x^2)}}$$
And in the case of an hexagonal lattice, I found in this post [An exact counting solution for the number of points within a circle of radius $r$ centered on a lattice point in a $A_2$ hexagonal lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110186/an-exact-counting-solution-for-the-number-of-points-within-a-circle-of-radius-r) that the number of points within a circle of radius r centered in the center is:
$$ N(r)= \sum_{x = -Floor(\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}})}^{Floor(\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}})}( 1 + 2 Floor(\sqrt{r^2 - 3 x^2}) +  \sum_{x = -Floor(\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}}^{Floor(\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{2}) - \frac{1}{2}}(  2 Floor(\sqrt{r^2 - 3 x^2} + \frac{1}{2}). $$
And I checked this expression with the values in http://oeis.org/A053416 and I don't obtain the same values for an r.
Can you guide me where I am wrong?
In my research I want to obtain the number of the lattice points for square and hexagonal lattices in function of lattice constant and region size.
[This is the structure that I obtain numerrically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRtk5.png)
I am new to this subject and I appreciate all the suggestions.

Comment: How can we guide you if you don't show your work? And anyway, this question might be better fit for [Math.SE].

Comment: From the mathematic point of view, the math behind this exact solutions for someone that doesn't not work in the field field (books). I did my structures numerically and now I need to find the number of points within a circle of radius r. For the square lattice the expression is checked, but what I find for the hexagonal lattice it's not correct or maybe I am wrong. I found this expression on a post here. I don't have the skills to check this expression so I would appreciate some help in this direction.

Comment: Is it possible that the mathoverflow link and the oeis link aren't counting exactly the same thing? Maybe they are situating the lattice differently with respect to the origin, or maybe they are not using hexagons of the same size?

Comment: As is in showed in that post, [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110186/an-exact-counting-solution-for-the-number-of-points-within-a-circle-of-radius-r](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110186/an-exact-counting-solution-for-the-number-of-points-within-a-circle-of-radius-r), it should give the same results. The only difference that I should take in the account is that in oeis link is expressed the number of points in function of the diameter of the circle and in the formula below it's expressed in function of the radius. But I took into account that.

Comment: The formula above I think it not correct because in the case of radius 1, the number of points should be 7 and  this is the number in oeis. But the person who has written this is claiming that it gives the results in oeis.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong somewhere. I don't think that the oeis is not using hexagons of the same size because I checked some values numerically

Comment: Are you sure you want OEIS A053416 and not [A308685](https://oeis.org/A308685)?

Comment: Looking on my structure, it seems that your suggestion may be correct, but I am not sure. My structure is like centered hexagonal numbers

Comment: Related question from same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416532/is-there-an-exact-solution-for-the-number-of-points-within-a-circle-of-radius-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By identifying the lattice points with numbers of the form $x - y\omega$, $\omega = e^{2\pi i / 3}$, $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, we find that we want to count Diophantine solutions to $x^2 + xy + y^2 \le r^2$. From $$\sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{m^2 + mn + n^2} = 1 + 6 \sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\frac{q^{3n+1}}{1 - q^{3n+1}} - \frac{q^{3n+2}}{1-q^{3n+2}}\right)$$ (see e.g. Michael D. Hirschhorn (1999) [Three Classical Results on Representations of a Number](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/wpapers/s42hirsch.pdf), Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire, B42f) we get $$N(r) = 1 + 6 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{r^2}{3k+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{r^2}{3k+2} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: Can you give me more references? This result is related to Eisenstein integer? How can we determine the multiple 6? And the "3k+1" and "3k+1"? I looked at Diophantine solutions and the material given by you, and some books. I need more basic understanding of this problems

Comment: @Mihaela, yes, the lattice points are the Eisenstein integers. Normally we'd write $x + y\omega$, but the bijection $y \leftrightarrow -y$ is straightforward and puts the norm in the right form to directly apply the identity. The multiple 6 is unsurprising: the hexagonal lattice has order 6 rotation. The extraction of $N(r)$ from the generating function is by treating it as a difference of geometric series: $$\frac{x}{1-x} = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$ so that $k$ in the second identity takes the part of $n$ on the right-hand side of the first.

Comment: @Mihaela, I've put an old [exposition of the Hirschhorn paper](https://cheddarmonk.org/papers/triangle-lattice.pdf) up on my website.

Comment: Can you get rid of infinity, on the sum, like in square lattice?

Comment: In the square lattice $$N(r) = 1 + 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{r^2}{4k+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{r^2}{4k+1} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: whhic gives $$N(r) = 1 + 4 \sum_{k=0}^{r^2}(-1)^{i-1}\left\lfloor  \frac{r^2}{2k-1} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: And the final answer is $$N(r) = 1 + 4\lfloor r \rfloor +  4\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor r \rfloor} \lfloor \sqrt{r^2 - k}\rfloor$$

Comment: in the first comment about this, at the last term is $4k + 3$

Comment: like here [https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)

Comment: @Mihaela, yes, once $3k + 2 > r^2$ the terms in the sum are all zero.

Comment: I get 0 using the condition to calculate until the old sums is different from the current sum for high values of r, for small values is working fine. I think it's the case  $(3k+2)>r^2$