# Is there an exact solution for the number of points within a circle of radius r for an honeycomb lattice?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices

I want to ask if exists an exact solution for the number of points within a circle of radius r  for an honeycomb lattice.
I know that it is exist for an square lattice https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html:
$$N(r)=1+4\lfloor r \rfloor+4 \sum_{x=1}^{\lfloor r \rfloor}{\left\lfloor \sqrt{r^2−x^2} \right\rfloor}$$
($\lfloor · \rfloor$ is the floor function.)
Can we write a similar counting function for the honeycomb lattice?
For an honeycomb lattice like this:
[An honeycomb lattice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rx6U.png)

Comment: There is a closely related [question about the hexagonal lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109515).

Comment: How is this different, Mihaela, from the question you asked earlier, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416474/the-exact-number-of-points-within-a-circle-of-radius-r-centered-on-a-lattice-poi (other than having less detail than that earlier question)?

Comment: This appears to be the hexagonal lattice with a sublattice removed, so the result should follow straightforwardly from the result for the hexagonal lattice.